# Timer not firing in console app after around 6 hours

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a console application which has a method running every 10 seconds. The method is triggered by a timer, according to the code below:

```
using System.Threading;
public class remoteConnectionManager
{
    private Timer heartbeatTimer = new Timer(heartbeatBegin, null, 10000, Timeout.Infinite);
    private void heartbeatBegin(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Heartbeat began");
        try{
            //Run code here
        }
        finally{
            heartbeatTimer.Change(10000, Timout.Infinite);
            Console.WriteLine("Timer changed");
        }
    }
}
public static class globalHolder
{
    public static remoteConnectionManager rConnMan = new remoteConnectionManager();
}
```

My problem is that after around 6 hours, the timer stops firing completely. The final output seen in the console is "heartbeat began".

I have tried using both System.Timer and System.Threading.Timer and both have the problem which leads me to suspect that this is an issue with my code. People have suggested that the timer is going out of scope but I'm not sure how this can be if the object is instatntiated statically.

Another solution I've tried is replacing the `heartbeatTimer.Change()` with

```
heartbeatTimer = new Timer(heartbeatBegin, null, 10000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

but it hasn't helped.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:** The console app is running on a windows 7 machine with sleep and windows update turned off

**EDIT 2:** I've tried implementing the `catch{}` part as well but to no avail. The timer still stops firing after a few hours.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to reset the timer after every call? If it's because the processing can take a while another way to do it is to use say a one second timer and just return if it's been under 10 seconds since the last call. According to the docs the `Change` method can fail and return false so maybe some sort of deadlock can cause it.

Comment: PeterJ, the reason i'm using the change method is exactly as you described, because the processing can take a while since it's doing network requests. But besides that, wouldn't the `heartbeatTimer =new Timer...` have fixed something like that? And I have tried it with System.Timer and it still doesn't fix this issue.

Comment: Where is the code running? on a Web Server or a Client App?

Comment: Daredevil, it is running as a client app on a windows 7 machine which has sleep settings and windows update turned off.

Comment: I just had a play around with the same code but with a 10ms interval and random 0-20ms delay in the processing loop and it didn't miss a beat over 15 minutes. If you haven't tried it already it might be worth logging the time and messages like "enter timer", "exit timer" to make sure it's not the processing code never returning.

Comment: PeterJ, I forgot to meantion that I did have some logging and I've now added it to the example code. The application ended up at "Timer Changed" after the timer stopped firing. Thanks for what you're doing though!

Comment: what happen if an exception is thrown from the line `//run code here`?

Comment: Because of the `try{} finally{}` even if an exception is thrown, the `finally` block will still run

Comment: Is the app still running even if timer is not firing any more? Maybe some uncaught exception somewhere else?

Comment: I am beginning to suspect some sort of uncaught exception with all these comments but the app does continue running, with other modules being unaffected.

Comment: try-finally still requires a catch block in the upper level. If the exception is unhandled the background thread is terminated silently leaving the app in running state. If finally block is executed eventually you can see it prints to the console. Do some experiment, throw an exception from that line to see what happens. My understanding might not be accurate I have not got a device to try it out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, kennyzx, I will definitely try a few experiments to see if this might be the issue. Thanks!